# SwiperJS not taking 100% height of div

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

I'm using swiperJS, with multiple images but I cannot seem to get it to take the full width and height of the div it's in. I have the following styling on my images:

```
.swiper-slide img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
```

}

Which would normally work on an `<img>` tag, but it seems to take the width into account but not the height.

I'm guessing something within swiper is resizing this, but I can't only seem to find `autoHeight` in the docs.

Here's a code snippet of my code:

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    autoHeight: true,
    loop: true,
    effect: "fade",
    autoplay: {
      delay: 2500,
      disableOnInteraction: true,
    },

    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      type: 'bullets',
    },

    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
    }
  })
```

```css
.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 40px; 
}

.slider-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.slider-container {
    width: 40%;
}

.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;

}

.swiper-slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.slider-content {
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.slider-content h3 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.slider-content p {
    font-weight: 200;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

.slider-content p:nth-of-type(3) {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.slider-content strong {
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="slider">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="slider-wrapper">
          <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="swiper-container">
              <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <img
                    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625523214628-4dec27885b68?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <img
                    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625628748830-639e59adbcfc?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1951&q=80"
                    alt=""
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
              <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
              <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-content">
            <h3>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Id,
              cupiditate.
            </h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit hic
              consequuntur odio tempore? Saepe, tenetur suscipit perspiciatis
              totam accusamus numquam pariatur nobis expedita in, neque,
              veritatis deserunt reiciendis id excepturi?
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit hic
              consequuntur odio tempore? Saepe, tenetur suscipit perspiciatis
              totam accusamus numquam pariatur nobis expedita in, neque,
              veritatis deserunt reiciendis id excepturi?
            </p>

            <p>
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus
              quam ducimus accusantium possimus, nihil exercitationem temporibus
              recusandae soluta quae voluptatibus.
            </p>
            <a class="btn" href="https://www.google.com">How it Works</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see where you have defined the height of swiper-container - it seems to be auto, but you mention the height of the element it is in. Am I looking at the wrong element?

Comment: Removing `width: 100%;` from `.swiper-slide img` seems to work.

Comment: the `.swiper-container` doesn't have a height value. I've tried 100% but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: removing the `width: 100%` does fill the whole div, but to the size of the image. I want to keep both the `.slider-container` and the `.slider-content` divs at the same height. so the image pushes to the bottom in line with the `.slider-content` text/button.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
.swiper-slide{
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: weird that the height 100% property doesn't work in some cases and only height: auto gets the job done. If some CSS wizard out there know why please explain!